# Is there a multi-particle version of the Pauli equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, approximations

The [Pauli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation) describes a non-relativistic spin-1/2 particle in an electromagnetic field. The solution is a two-component wave function.

However, what if we have a system of two particles that interact with each other electromagnetically (e.g., two electrons)? In general, the motion of the particles would create electromagnetic radiation and one would probably have to use the full formalism of QED to describe the situation exactly (but even in this case, there are some approximate approaches like the Breit equation).

However, in the non-relativistic regime, does there exist something like the Pauli equation for this situation? I assume the resulting wavefunction would be a 4-component object corresponding to the different spin states of the two particles.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the multi-particle Schrödinger equation with extra spin factors?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like what you are describing is Non-Relativistic Quantum Electro-Dynamics (NRQED). This is the appropriate non-relativistic limit of QED, where the particle degrees of freedom are described by a two-component spinor, the antiparticle degrees of freedom by a two-component spinor, and there is separate particle and antiparticle number conservation (i.e. there is no Schwinger pair-creation possible). $\alpha_\text{EM}$ corrections can be treated perturbatively. Note that the equations of motion of NRQED give you the Pauli Equation.

Early papers include [this one](https://inspirehep.net/literature/213093), I'm not sure of any nice review articles/textbooks though. NRQED/NRQCD is used extensively to describe bound states of heavy particles (e.g. muonium, made up of muon-antimuon). Note also that there is a related theory known as pNRQED (p stands for potential) where you also integrate out the `soft modes' that are on the same order as the relative momenta of the particles in the bound state: this "fixes the power counting" and is to some extent more physically interpretable.